# If I only know $f'(x) = e^{x^2}$, how do I evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$?

Tags: analysis

Specifically, I need to show that it equals $\infty$. I remember writing the solution down somewhere, though I can't find it and can't remember it, so I'm mostly looking for an outline of how to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use L'Hopital's rule to get something that you can immediately evaluate.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't recognize that was the right path since I wasn't sure how to show that $lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ was $\infty$, but I realized that it follows pretty easily from the MVT.

Comment: @access: as long as $f'(x)\ge1$, we get $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

I suppose you noticed that $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ is just the derivative of $\log (f(x))$.

This could help you goind faster to the solution.